# PHP Spreadsheet / Laravel Excel - Date format in CSV converts to the users local format after editing

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) which is based on [PHP Spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to allow users to download a file, edit it and then upload.

I then simply loop through each Cell and compare the value to detect any changes.

However the date format is changing and thus being flagged as a change, even when there is none.

If I export the file as XLS then dates seem to be converted to a timestamp and are really easy to work with e.g.

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue())
```

However if I export as CSV then i'm manually setting the format to Y-m-d (this seems easiest since nobody in the world uses Y-d-m so the format should be clear).

But when I open the CSV on my local machine, edit some non date field and save it, then the dates are then converted to d/m/Y (my local format).

So if I export 2000-12-25 I get back 25/12/2000.

In this specific example obviously I know the format is d/m/Y because it's my local machine, but since this could be used by anyone in the world the cell value could be the date in a huge range of formats and I need to find a way of knowing what format the date is in.

Is there some way to detect the date format from the headers in the CSV file or something like that?